# Integrals to calculate the volume of a cylinder bounded by a plane that cuts the cylinder's base

Tags: calculus, integration, volume, solid-geometry

I was given a problem where I had to calculate the volume for a cylinder of equation $x^2+y^2=25$ and bounded by the planes $xy$ and $x+y+z=8$. No trouble. But what if the plane cuts the cylinder's base, like the plane x+y+z=4, how should I do it?